# Override static method in WC_Shortcodes class (shortcode)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode, oop

I'm trying to override `product_categories` shortcode from WooCommerce, so that I can add additional classes to the wrapper

```
[product_categories number="0" parent="0" class="container"]
```

So I looked at the [WooCommerce code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/dc7aa3069466f1b7e23fd7ef468760a6a9ddd241/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php), and created a class that extends `WC_Shortcodes` and I just copied the static method `product_categories`

```
  /**
   * Updated product categories shortcode
   *
   * List all (or limited) product categories.
   *
   * @param array $atts Attributes.
   * @return string
   */
  public static function product_categories( $atts ) {
    if ( isset( $atts['number'] ) ) {
      $atts['limit'] = $atts['number'];
    }

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit'      => '-1',
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'columns'    => '4',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'parent'     => '',
        'ids'        => '',
        'class'      => '',
    ), $atts, 'product_categories' );
    $ids        = array_filter( array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $atts['ids'] ) ) );
    $hide_empty = ( true === $atts['hide_empty'] || 'true' === $atts['hide_empty'] || 1 === $atts['hide_empty'] || '1' === $atts['hide_empty'] ) ? 1 : 0;
    // Get terms and workaround WP bug with parents/pad counts.
    $args = array(
        'orderby'    => $atts['orderby'],
        'order'      => $atts['order'],
        'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
        'include'    => $ids,
        'pad_counts' => true,
        'child_of'   => $atts['parent'],
    );
    $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
    if ( '' !== $atts['parent'] ) {
      $product_categories = wp_list_filter( $product_categories, array(
          'parent' => $atts['parent'],
      ) );
    }
    if ( $hide_empty ) {
      foreach ( $product_categories as $key => $category ) {
        if ( 0 === $category->count ) {
          unset( $product_categories[ $key ] );
        }
      }
    }
    $atts['limit'] = '-1' === $atts['limit'] ? null : intval( $atts['limit'] );
    if ( $atts['limit'] ) {
      $product_categories = array_slice( $product_categories, 0, $atts['limit'] );
    }
    $columns = absint( $atts['columns'] );
    wc_set_loop_prop( 'columns', $columns );
    wc_set_loop_prop( 'is_shortcode', true );
    ob_start();
    if ( $product_categories ) {
      woocommerce_product_loop_start();
      foreach ( $product_categories as $category ) {
        wc_get_template( 'content-product_cat.php', array(
            'category' => $category,
        ) );
      }
      woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    }
    woocommerce_reset_loop();
    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . ' ' . $atts['class'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
  }
```

And initialized it when I initialize a theme (I'm using [this boilerplate](https://github.com/infinum/wp-boilerplate)).

Obiously this isn't working. I even tried to remove it and just add the modified one using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21265771/629127), but that didn't work.

Is my only option to make a new shortcode and use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can (or should) remove the default Shortcode:

```
// Hook after `WC_Shortcodes::init()` is executed.
add_action( 'init', function(){
    // Remove the shortcode.
    remove_shortcode( 'product_categories' );

    // Add it back, but using our callback.
    add_shortcode( 'product_categories', 'my_product_categories_shortcode' );
}, 11 );
```

And here's how you can modify the *default* Shortcode's output:

```
function my_product_categories_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $out = WC_Shortcodes::product_categories( $atts );

    // Modify the wrapper's opening tag.
    if ( ! empty( $atts['class'] ) ) {
        $columns = isset( $atts['columns'] ) ?
            absint( $atts['columns'] ) : 4;

        $out = str_replace(
            '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . '">',
            '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . ' ' . esc_attr( $atts['class'] ) . '">',
            $out
        );
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Or if you want, you can copy [the whole code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocommerce/tags/3.4.1/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php#L149) (i.e. clone it) and then do whatever your heart desires:

```
function my_product_categories_shortcode( $atts ) {
    if ( isset( $atts['number'] ) ) {
        $atts['limit'] = $atts['number'];
    }

    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'limit'      => '-1',
        'orderby'    => 'name',
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'columns'    => '4',
        'hide_empty' => 1,
        'parent'     => '',
        'ids'        => '',
        'class'      => '', // the extra arg
    ), $atts, 'product_categories' );

    // ... refer to the link I provided

    return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $columns . ' ' . esc_attr( $atts['class'] ) . '">' .
        ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I ended up just creating my own instead of overriding existing, seemed like a less fuss. Thanks

Comment: I actually wanted to suggest doing so, and I'm glad you chose to do that. Anyway, thanks for accepting my answer. =)